# How to read avro bytes field

Tags: byte, apache-nifi, avro

i use nifi for consume kafka message which are in avro format.

the schema is not embedded in the avro file, i have to set it manually.

for one field, schema is :

```
{
    "name" : "body",
    "type": ["null", "bytes"],
    "default": null
  }
```

the real field content is a concatenation of a string and a zip file.
My goal is to extract the zip and i don't know how to achieve this.

I try to use update record nifi service with one avroReader and jsonWriter.

if i set "bytes" type in the schema:

```
{
    "name" : "body",
    "type": ["null", "bytes"],
    "default": null
  }
```

the output is like this :

```
[{"body":[53,50,53,59,48,48,48,56,59,67,49,48,57,48,54,52,50,49,51,48,52,50,50,80,75,3,4,20,0,0,0,8,0,-43,72,-115,...]}]
```

if i set "string" type in the schema :

```
{
    "name" : "body",
    "type": ["null", "string", "bytes"],
    "default": null
  }
```

the output is like this :

```
000\u0000F{\u0000\u0000\"\u0000\u001C\u0000path/fio/file.zip\t\u0000\u0003��Vb��Vbux\u000B\u0000\u...
```

In the two case, i don't know how to handle the output with nifi or groovy or java for extract the zip file from this field.

I think the best way should be with de first try (bytes type) but how to convert the jsonarray in bytes ?

Thanks for your help